# What causes g++ ignoring nonexisting directory

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, g++

I am learning to use make. I am trying to compile a program using g++ on my home machine that I have successfully compiled using xl on a school machine. I am trying to link with an external library that I built and placed in a separate directory. I am trying to include the header file, but g++ claims the include directory does not exist. The include directory definitely exists, tab complete fills it in and `find` locates it as well.

Why does g++ decide the directory does not exist? In general what causes a directory to be ignored? I want to know why this is breaking so I can better write makefiles. More importantly to me, how do I fix this and have g++ search for arbitrary header files in whatever directory I tell it to look in?

I have seen questions about g++ ignoring directories, but those were in the case of ignoring various system default locations. They usually solved their problem by removing a conflicting version or just re installing their tool. My problem is different because g++ is ignoring a user defined directory that actually exists.

```
src/a3.cc:1:17: fatal error: apf.h: No such file or directory
#include "apf.h"

$ find /home/USER/Documents/GitHub/core/apf/
/home/USER/Documents/GitHub/core/apf/
/home/USER/Documents/GitHub/core/apf/apfUserData.cc
 ....
/home/USER/Documents/GitHub/core/apf/apf.h

....
```

I have tried manually specifying the directory in the make file using `-I`

```
apf = /home/USER/Documents/Github/core/apf/
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -Wall -g -I $(apf) --pedantic-errors --verbose
```

I have also tried setting CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH = $(apf)
```

For each of these attempts I see the same error, that g++ is "ignoring nonexistant directory"

```
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/g++

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/USER/Documents/Github/core/apf/"

ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/include-fixed"
 ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/local/include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
 #include "..." search starts here:
 #include <...> search starts here:
 ./inc
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/x86_64-redhat-linux
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/../../../../include/c++/4.9.2/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6), GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 954ba53e83b294b646fa1b6b73a69682
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have a case sensitive file system. You have `GitHub` in some places and `Github` in others. Make them all match correctly and you'll be in better shape.

Comment: Thats it! now I feel kinda bad for asking this.